# Jekyll: How to include specific file from collection?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a collection of css files I combine into one with Jekyll. This is very easy:

```
{% for file in site.css %}
{{ file }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, there is a special case where I want to include just a single one of those files. The `pages.css` file.

`site.css` is a collection, so I simply put all my css files in a folder called `_css` and in `_config.yml` added:

```
collections:
  css:
    output: false
```

I was able to include only the `_css/pages.css` files using `{{ site.css | where:"title", "Pages" | first }}`. But I was wondering if there is a nicer way of doing it. Something like `{{ site.css/pages.css }}`

Is there a way to do it like that? Wihtout a `where` and `first` clause?

Comment: How is `site.css` defined?

Comment: @marcanuy I added some info about site.css to the original question. It's just a collection.

Comment: Why did you use a collection instead of adding them directly to the css folder?

Comment: @marcanuy That way I can easily combine them into one big css file that will be added to the actual webpages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the exception I would use an if statement and not loop over the files.

However, I would consider cache while using this solution. If one pages uses 'superlargecombined.css' and another one uses 'superlargecombinedcsswithoutonepart.css' the client needs to download them both (fully). That is in not an optimization. If you keep your css files seperated they can be cached and will be downloaded once, independent of your page css configuration. Combining things that always need to stick together is a good solution though (to minimize requests), but note that with HTTP2 the need to minimize requests will reduce drastically.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You make a good point there. The exception just needs only one css, rather than all. So it's a really small file. But still, the main page uses the superlargecombined.css, so the very small one is still extra data that needs to be downloaded because 99% of the time the user will go through the main page.